# What word has the root "vale" in it?

Tags: morphology, roots

This really seems to be a strange question, but I just came cross a word *valediction*, I looked it up and found out that *vale* means "farewell". Even though I'm not that keen into etymology, this word is so beautifully constructed and I never felt this way about a word before.

Is there any word that also has the root *vale* in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only other modern word I know of to employ the same root actually stems from “valediction” itself.

> ### valedictorian (n.)
>
> "student who pronounces the oration at commencement exercises of his or her class," 
> 1832, American English 
> <sub>Source: [etymonline.com definition of “valedictorian”](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=valedictorian&searchmode=none)</sub>

Side note:

*“Valē”* is the 2nd-person singular imperative of *“valēre”*, which means “to be well”. English has done away with most declensions such as this, so now it's “farewell” whether you’re saying it to one person or a ham.

UPDATE: I found [a list of words derived from *“valēre”*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_words_by_Latin_antecedents#V):

> [ambivalence](/wiki/ambivalence), [ambivalent](/wiki/ambivalent), [avail](/wiki/avail), [countervail](/wiki/countervail), [convalesce](/wiki/convalesce), [equivalent](/wiki/equivalent), [equivalence](/wiki/equivalence), [evaluate](/wiki/evaluate), [evaluation](/wiki/evaluation), [evaluator](/wiki/evaluator), [invalid](/wiki/invalid), [invalidate](/wiki/invalidate), [overvalue](/wiki/overvalue), [overvaluation](/wiki/overvaluation), [prevail](/wiki/prevail), [prevalent](/wiki/prevalent), [prevalence](/wiki/prevalence), [reevaluate](/wiki/reevaluate), [reevaluation](/wiki/reevaluation), [undervalue](/wiki/undervalue), [undervaluation](/wiki/undervaluation), [valance](/wiki/valance), [valence](/wiki/valence), [valency](/wiki/valency), [valediction](/wiki/valediction), [valetudinary](/wiki/valetudinary), [valiance](/wiki/valiance), [valiant](/wiki/valiant), [valid](/wiki/valid), [validate](/wiki/validate), [validation](/wiki/validation), [validity](/wiki/validity), [valor](/wiki/valor), [valuable](/wiki/valuable), [valuation](/wiki/valuation), [value](/wiki/value)

They may not all seem very related, but remember that one sense of “well” is basically “strong” and indeed *“valē”* is purported to descend from the Proto-Indo-European **wal* (“be strong”).[¹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valeo#Latin)